# Is it recommended to use application gateway to load balance database servers?

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

I have 3 database servers in Azure , I want to load balance between them , For application servers I am using application gateway.

Now I am not sure which one ( application gateway or traditional load balancer) should I use for load balancing database servers.

Can anyone clear my confusion?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-auto-failover-group are you talking about  failover group?

Answer (score 1):

Application Gateway is a Layer 7 load balancer, which means it only works with web traffic (HTTP, HTTPS, WebSocket, and HTTP/2).

I believe a database server would expose a TCP endpoint, but not a web endpoint.

For this reason, you would need a traditional load balancer, which works on Layer 4.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#how-do-application-gateway-and-azure-load-balancer-differ